# Use pointer to an int as an array index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indexing, char

I have the following code which is a piece of a larger program. I am attempting to pass an int to a function that will copy part of a char array ( name[100] ) to another until a certain character is reached, and update the int value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void time_loop(int *a, char name[100], char *data, char until_char)
{
    int c = 0;    
    while(name[*a] != until_char)
    {
        data[c] = name[*a];
        a++;
        c++;
    }
    a = a +  2;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    char name[100] = {' ', ' ', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'o', ':', '\0'};
    char fill_this[15];

    time_loop(&i, name, fill_this, ':');
    printf("current char index: %d\n", i);
    printf("the word is: %s", fill_this);

    return 0;
}
```

Currently the code runs until it hits the:

```
while(name[*a] != until_char)
```

piece of code, with a problem accessing *a.

I could always just take the easy way out and change the function to:

```
int time_loop(int a, char name[100], char *data, char until_char)
```

and return an int, but there has to be a way to do this correctly.

**Q: What is the correct way to pass a type int* as an index number for an array?**

Comment: You want to increment the *integer* pointed to by `a`. That is: `(*a) ++`! Likewise for the final one, I guess you want `*a = *a + 2` i.e. `*a += 2`

Comment: ...but of course the function returns `void`...

Comment: Also you're not zero-terminating `fill_this`

Comment: Easy fix! Thank you!

Comment: ... and you should guard against the case that the string doesn't contain `until_char`.

Comment: @Robert James Mieta  What is the purpose of this statement  a = a +  2;?

Comment: Please do not edit answers into the question. Answers go into the Answer box. You can accept a posted answer, or you can post your own answer if none are suitable

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow it’s a part of a much larger program where incoming words are separated with “, ” hence advancing 2 index numbers ahead to the next word. I would pass ‘,’ as argument to until_char instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not modifying the integer in some cases, you're modifying the pointer to it. For example:

```
a++
a = a + 2
```

both do **pointer arithmetic** - they modify the pointer, not the value pointed to by it. What you want instead is:

```
(*a)++
*a += 2
```

These perform the modifications on the value itself, not the pointer.

---

Note that as you're not doing bounds-checking, you can run over the end of the array (if the character you're searching for isn't in the array), which is undefined behaviour. You should also be sure to null-terminate your output string - add a `\0` after the last character. Not doing this can cause undefined behaviour later on if you try to print the string.